# How to use default laravel exceptions?

Tags: laravel-backpack

Laravel Backpack throws it's own exception views but I don't want it to happen. How can I disable this and use default Laravel ones?

Answer (score 0):

Upon installation, Backpack\Base has published some error views in your `resources/errors`. If you delete those files, Laravel should use its default error files.